# How to distinguish routing to the same POST method with TModel and IEnumerable<TModel> in ASP.NET Core

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, .net-core

I have a controller at .Net Core 2.2 Web API.

There is a POST method which is responsible for creation of an entity.
A current need is to add another POST method to be able to create many.
Here is the sample code I have (no other routing is used):

```
[Route("api/[controller]")]
public class SampleController: BaseController
{
    [HttpPost]
    public Task<IActionResult> Create([FromBody] SampleModel model) {...}

    [HttpPost]
    public Task<IActionResult> CreateMany([FromBody] IEnumerable<SampleModel> models) {...}
}
```

As far as exception message says these two are ambiguous routes. But for me it seems not quiet clear. In fact actions' arguments are different types. Might be I am missing something or it is a natural restriction?

Comment: Use `HttpPost("createmany")]` to give the second action a new URL.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In HTTP there are no "actions" and "arguments".

When your app receives POST request to api/Sample, app infrastructure must dispatch request somewhere. `Create` and `CreateMany` serves the same route, so it's impossible to choose one of them.

You can either modify route for one of these actions, e.g. using `HttpPost("CreateMany")]`, or remove the first action, since it is superfluous.

Comment: I wouldn't say the first action is superfluous - they both take different types of input. You could have a custom model binder that knows how to convert a single item to an `IEnumerable` though.

Comment: Now I see, thanks. I could play around with HttpGet as far as it has additional routing via arguments, yet there would be ambiguity in POST without specifying more routing.